# htaccess error 400 when % in url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^infos/)^(.+?)/?$ /test.php?f=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This htaccess will return an error 400 if i try to access http://www.example.com/test%test

test.php:

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

result:

```
f=error/400.html
```

how can I escape the % symbol in htaccess ?
Is there any other characters that can cause the same problem ?

Comment: Look at great jdMorgan answer to your question: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4220265.htm

Comment: ok then can i use htaccess to replace % by XYZ ? So if i get a request with http://www.example.com/test%test it would redirect to http://www.example.com/testXYZtest

Answer (score 0):

To escape the % in mod_rewrite you can use the `B` flag. It is used to escape non-alphanumeric characters. Let me know if that works for you.

e.g.

```
RewriteRule (?!^infos/)^(.+?)/?$ /test.php?f=$1 [B,L,QSA,NC]
```